# Errno::ENOENT when running Rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed the gem koudoku and with the command `rails g koudoku:install user` I am getting a error. I have done a search and can not find a fix for it. I am not sure what to do. If someone has some advice that would be helpful!

```
    generate  model
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- bin/rails (LoadError)
        gsub  app/models/subscription.rb
    generate  model
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- bin/rails (LoadError)
        gsub  app/models/plan.rb
    generate  model coupon code:string free_trial_length:string
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- bin/rails (LoadError)
        gsub  app/models/coupon.rb
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:232:in `binread': No such file or directory - /Users/dating/app/models/coupon.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:232:in `gsub_file'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/koudoku-0.0.11/lib/generators/koudoku/install_generator.rb:50:in `install'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `each'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `map'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/group.rb:233:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/generators.rb:156:in `invoke'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Run `rails g` and check if you see `koudoku:install` listed in the generators list. Also, did you run `bundle install` command after adding `gem koudoku` in your Gemfile.

Comment: Yes I ran bundle installed, it shows it as being there. It's also in the generators list.

Comment: Run `ls -la /Users/dating/app/models/coupon.rb`  and check if you get the file listed because that's the file  at that exact location which `koudoku installer` is looking for.

Comment: correct. I had to create that file. Thanks for the obvious point out.

Answer (score 0):

As Kirti Thorat noted in the comments I had to create the models first and then run the generator.